# not able delete session in passport github strategy

Tags: express, github, oauth-2.0, passport.js, express-session

I am using passport js to access the Github API. My versions are
passport@0.4.0,passport-github2@0.1.11,express-session@1.17.0,express@4.17.1.

Am able to get access token and access github api successfully but not able to log out properly. I am using the following code.

```
app.use(session({ secret: 'secret key', resave: true, saveUninitialized: true ,cookie: { maxAge: 100000 }  }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.get('/logout',function(req,res){
  req.logout();
  req.session.destroy(function (err) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }

    res.redirect('/login');
  });

})
```

when i click log out button in my app, it was logged out and not able to access authenticated URL. My problem is when i access https://github.com/ in another tab the user session is still active. How to revoke the access token?. I don't want to use [OAuth Authorizations API](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth_authorizations/#delete-an-authorization), its going to be removed on November, 13, 2020.